# Problem when attempting to get the url from the dropbox API function sharing_list_shared_links

Tags: python, dropbox

I am trying to create a shared link to a dropbox folder, or share an existing link if there is one. When no link exists I can create one and get the url without problem, but when trying to access the url from an existing link I get the error 'ListSharedLinksResult' object has no attribute 'url'. Here is my function:

```
def get_share_link(path):
try:
    shared_link_metadata = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings(path)
    print(shared_link_metadata)
    print(shared_link_metadata.url)
except:
    print('Link already created')
    existing_link_metadata = dbx.sharing_list_shared_links(path, cursor=None, direct_only=None)
    print(existing_link_metadata)
    print(existing_link_metadata.url)
```

Though I can see the url in the ListSharedLinksResult when printed..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListSharedLinksResult` type does not have a `url` attribute. It contains a list of links in the `links` attribute. So, you can do something like this:

```
        for link in existing_link_metadata.links:
            print(link.url)
```